# Calling node js function from main.ts (electron js and angular js integration)

Tags: javascript, angular, electron

I follow this tutorial how to integrate electron js and angular js.

https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-desktop-electron

I already run this and it worked well, but now the problem is I want to start to call node js function from angular js and electron js from `main.ts`

Example, when button pressed on angular js side I need to invoke the function on node js file and send back the response.

Answer (score -1):

For communications in Electron, you can use `ipcMain` ([docs](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main).

In your Electron code, add a listener with something like:

```
import { ipcMain } from 'electron';
ipcMain.on('REQUEST_CHANNEL', (event: any, arg: any) =>
  console.log('received', event, arg);
);
```

In your angular application, install the module `ngx-electron` (`npm i --save ngx-electron`), and then send a message to Electron, with something like the following:

```
import { ElectronService } from 'ngx-electron';
import { IpcRenderer } from 'electron';

// inject the service
public renderer: IpcRenderer;
constructor(
    private electronServiceInstance: ElectronService
) {
    this.renderer = this.electronServiceInstance.ipcRenderer;
}

// send the message
this.renderer.send('REQUEST_CHANNEL', 'my message');
```

To send back the response, you can use several ways. 
What I do suggest, is to do the opposite. 
On Angular side with `IpcRenderer` listen on messages from another channel, like `'RESPONSE_CHANNEL'` for example, and from Electron send messages through that channel when you want that Angular will capture them.

Comment: the tutorial says main.ts using typescript meanwhile i already create function on javascript (node js), is it possible to change main.ts to main.js?